# C# How to declare more than 1 object?

Tags: c#

I made a Room Class, (it has length, width, height as integers) but I would like to make 2 different objects (because 1 declared Class is for 1 room, and the program would ask the user "How many rooms do you want to have?" or something like that...)

How can I make 2 or 3 different rooms, from the Room class?

here is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Feladatok1_20
{
    public class Exercise55TEST
    {
        public static void exercise()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("How many rooms would you like to work in?");
            int numberOfRooms = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            List<int> room = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRooms; i++)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("How long is the room? (length)");
                int length = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                //room.Add(length);

                System.Console.WriteLine("How high is the room? (height)");
                int height = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                //room.Add(height);

                System.Console.WriteLine("How wide is the room? (width)");
                int width = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                //room.Add(width);

                int area = width*length;
                int wallArea = length*height;
                int ceilingArea = width*length;

                room.Add(area);
                room.Add(wallArea);
                room.Add(ceilingArea);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

here is the Class I made:

```
namespace Feladatok1_20
{
    public class Exercise55
    {
        public int length;

        public int height;
        public int width;


    }
}
```

Comment: Why is your list an int-list, not `Room`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1. rename your class

```
public class Room
{
    public int length { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    // those can be calculated so I would declare readonly properties with get-only
    public int area { get { return width * length; } }
    public int wallArea { get { return  length * height; } }
}
```

side note: `wallArea` should be

```
public int wallArea { get { return  2 * ((length * height) + (width * height)); } }
```

and the area of the ceiling equals the area of the floor so one properie `area` is enough

## 2. declare a List of rooms instead of integers

```
List<Room> roomList = new List<Room>();
```

## 3. create you rooms

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRooms; i++)
{
    //Console.ReadLine and int.Parse here 
    roomList.Add(new Room(){ length = inputLength, width = inputWidth, height = inputHeight});
```

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about doing it with a List, but I didn't know how to put it together...Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

Create a List of objects of class "Room" and then add one object whenever you have to add for example:

```
List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();
    Console.WriteLine("How many rooms do you want to have?");
    int count = Console.ReadLine(Convert.ToIn16());
 for(int i=0l i<count; i++)
{
rooms.Add(new Room());
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So, make a List of Room, call it "rooms", then add as many "Room" objects to it, as the user inputs.